# add a UIView as a observer of a NSNotificationCenter message

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

How do I add a UIView as an observer of a NSNotificationCenter message?

I need to communicate between one View(CustomView1.m) to another View(CustomView2.m). preferably without touching the code in the VIewCOntroller.

Here is how I am trying it at the moment:

Posting the Notification from MyView1.m

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"InviteEmailClosedNotification"
     object:self];
```

Receiving the Notification in my MyView2.m

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(inviteEmailClosed)
                                                 name:@"InviteEmailClosedNotification"
                                               object:nil];
```

doing something when received:

```
- (void) inviteEmailClosed{
   NSLOG(@"DO SOMETHING HERE");
}
```

I have a UIView defined in a xib and I am adding it to a viewcontroller.

Comment: unclear what you're asking?

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I need to send a notification from one view to another on a view controller... Preferably without writing the code in the viewcontroller and writing it so that the two views communicate with each other.

Comment: Please expand your question to indicate what isn't working, and what you are doing to post the notification as well. At the moment, there's very little to answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listening from a ViewController instead a view solved my problem although not 100% ideal.

Answer (score 0):

In the class you specify for `addObserver:self` , instead of self, give the class that should be observering the message, or if the observerer is added in the class, self is correct to use.

Edit: are you sure you set the UIView in nib to be correct subclass MyView2?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine - that's the correct way to do it. So I'm going to guess what your problem is.

- Are these lines of code being run at all? Set breakpoints on them and see.
- If you've got a `UIView` defined in a xib, have you remembered to set it's class to be the class you want instead of leaving it as `UIView`?
- Is `self` really the object you want to add as the observer (it probably is).
- Have you set a breakpoint on `themeChanged` and seen if it's being called at all?
- Is `@"InviteEmailClosedNotification"` *definitely* the name of your notification?

Hope these random suggestions help.

S

PS Using a string for a notification name isn't a great idea - you should probably define it somewhere and use that constant instead. i.e.

```
#define InviteEmailClosedNotification @"InviteEmailClosedNotification"
```

This will stop typos :)

Comment: I will create a notification center class for static strings thanks for that suggestion :). I want to observe from one class to another (both subclasses of UIView; not UIViewCOntrollers). does this help to clarify :)?

Comment: Your code looks fine - there must be something else going on. Are you sure you're actually _sending_ the notification? (try putting an NSLog or a breakpoint to see).

Comment: ok so this didnt help. I NSLogged to see what is being reached. The broadcast is being sent... However, the UIViews are not receiving them.

Comment: Are you definitely running the line of code that adds the observer -  try an NSLog there as well to check

Answer (score 0):

While Posting the Notification from MyView1.m
set object to nil.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"InviteEmailClosedNotification"
     object:nil];
```

Comment: what is the reason for this mate :)?

Comment: That won't make a difference - because the notification listener passes `nil` for it's object parameter it will already be listening for `InviteEmailClosedNotification`s from _any_ object.

Comment: setting object as nil will broadcast your notification anywhere in the app.

Comment: ok so this didnt help. I NSLogged to see what is being reached. The broadcast is being sent... However, the UIViews are not receiving them.